# Can't access my IP camera over the internet

Tags: ip, port, nat, port-forwarding, camera

### EDIT: My problem is solved, please read comments 2-5 and 8,9.

I have an EasyN F3 (F3-M166) IP camera. It works fine on local IP address, but I can't access it over internet. This is what I have done step by step:

1. I configured the local IP (**camera_ip**) and port (**camera_port**) of the camera, using the software from the vendor's website: http://p2.ipcam.hk/
2. I opened `http://**camera_ip**:camera_port` and it works. The page asks me username and password, I login and I see the camera video output.
3. On my router (Netgear dg834gt) I forwarded the camera port this way:

   - Service -> Add custom service

     - Name: camera1
     - Type: TCP/UDP (overkill)
     - port: **camera_port**
   - Apply
   - Firewall rules -> Inbound Services -> Add

     - Service: camera1
     - Action: allow always
     - Send to LAN Server: **camera_ip**
     - WAN users:  any
   - Apply
4. I have discovered my external IP (**external_ip**) address with http://www.whatismyip.com/
5. Then I tried to browse the address: `http://**external_ip**:camera_port`.

Result: the connection times out and nothing happens. The external IP was not changed in the meantime. The router logs a lot of events like this one:

```
Wed, 2013-10-16 16:51:17 - TCP Packet - Source:**local_pc_ip**,2119 Destination:**external_ip**,*camera_port* - [camera1 rule match]
```

My question seems similar to [#400855](https://serverfault.com/questions/400855/ip-camera-working-on-lan-but-not-on-internet), but in my case not even the http forwarding is working.

Comment: You can also consider setting up a VPN connection in to your local network if you have a pfSense box setup or a hardware firewall box that allows for VPN connections. Otherwise, we need specific hardware information and what you have tried so far to port forward :)

Comment: Are you trying to go to http:/externalip:port from behind the router?

Comment: @DanBig: yes, should I try to go try from a friend's pc? By the way,  http:/externalip only works and open the router setting page.

Comment: Uh, yeah, its not going to work from the inside.

Comment: @Dan: Nope, it does not work.

Comment: @FrankThornton: well, I wrote in my answer what I tryed to port forward my camera. About HW infos, it's here: http://www.easynp.com/ProductsShow.aspx?id=436 (camera) and here: http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/DG834GT/DG834GT_DS_26Oct04.pdf (router).

Comment: Can you validate that port forwarding works to another device? E.g. from outside your network to a port on your local PC (run netcat or a local service on the test port).

Comment: For your information. There is [NAT loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) technology which allows to connect to one's own public IP address from inside the network. Though, router should support it. (I state it here only because it was mentioned above)

Comment: @Nikolay: so you have to add the domain to the host file. I finally understood why sometomes you have to modify that file. By the way, the first problem was caused by loopback, the second problem was caused by the ip camera, that works randomly.

Comment: @LucasMalor, good. Have you resolved the issue now?

Comment: @Nikolay: sorry for the delay, yes, I tested the cams using a phone with 3g connectivity.

Comment: Keep in mind that some ISP's also put multiple users behind one IP address so you wouldn't be able to access it unless you have a Static IP. Do you know if this is case?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to your external IP from inside your own LAN? If so, no wonder you are failing: that's called `hairpinning` and it is generally impossible for most routers, unless suitably configured (and this too can be done only on some routers).

Comment: Although this question is old, it has been bumped to the front page. Although the OP has put that their question has been answered, they haven't put or recommended an answer that can be selected as the best answer...